# Multiple CREATE TABLE AS statements in single stored procedure on Teradata

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, teradata

I have a stored procedure which is supposed to `DROP` 3 tables and then run 3 `CREATE TABLE AS` statements. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work as only 1 `DDL` statement is allowed in a single stored procedure by default as I'm getting following error message:

> Only an ET or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement.

Is there any other way that I'm missing how to place multiple `DDL` / `CREATE TABLE AS` statements in a single stored procedure or do I really have to create a single stored procedure for each `DDL` statement?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: How you tried to COMMIT each DDL statement in your stored procedure?

Comment: try https://support.teradata.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=ccf78be31b97fb00682ca8233a4bcbeb

Comment: @jarlh Yes, but I'm getting 'COMMIT WORK not allowed for a DBC/SQL session.' when trying to use COMMIT;

Comment: Can you DELETE/INSERT rather than DROP/CREATE? It is poor practice for a stored procedure to end a multi-statement transaction initiated outside the procedure. If these are VOLATILE tables, consider GLOBAL TEMPORARY tables instead - with the structure predefined and a session-local instance materialized in the SP by INSERT rather than CREATE TABLE AS.  Otherwise you should carefully reconsider your transaction boundaries. If you insist, the statement used in Teradata mode is END TRANSACTION or ET rather than COMMIT.